# xampp not running in limited user account

Tags: apache2, windows-xp, xampp, tomcat

I have installed xampp in widows xp from admin account. it is running properly for the users who have administrator previlage, but it is not running in limited user account. kindly provide me a solution. Iam using xampp 1.7.2 (32 bit)

Comment: Questions on Ask Ubuntu are expected to relate to Ubuntu within the scope defined in the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a Ubuntu specific Q&A site you'll need to ask your question either at the [XAMPP Support site](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/contact.html) or try [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or another [stackexchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#)

Comment: ok...tnks...i have solved the above issue by enabling user permission to that xampp folder. Thanks for the support